# Compare value of JSONObject with boolean value

Tags: json, key-value

I have my JsonObject having key as identified and value as`true` or`false`(Boolean). Next time I have to check whether that key is`true` or `false` so I am doing something like this:

```
JSONObject eachCaseJsonObject = new JSONObject();
eachCaseJsonObject.put("JSON_IS_IDENTIFIED", true);
```

now I want to check value of key`JSON_IS_IDENTIFIED` and I am doing this :

```
"true".equalsIgnoreCase(eachCaseJsonObject.get(JSON_IS_IDENTIFIED).toString())
```

But I want boolean value directly using key`JSON_IS_IDENTIFIED` and have to check it for `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use:

```
eachCaseJsonObject.getBoolean("JSON_IS_IDENTIFIED")
```